# how to round up the number for array format in .txt output i n python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract my analysis result in .txt file. The results show as below :

```
-3.298409999999999854e+04 -3.298409999999999854e+04 
-3.297840000000000146e+04 -3.297840000000000146e+04
```

Code:

```
anodeIdx = [10,20,30]

stressAnodeXX = [x for i,x in enumerate(stress_xx[0].Y) if i in anodeIdx]
stressAnodeYY = [x for i,x in enumerate(stress_yy[0].Y) if i in anodeIdx]

np.savetxt('Stress_strain_Anode.txt',np.c_[stressAnodeXX,stressAnodeYY])
```

I expected the result to be `-32984.1`  but the actual output is `-3.2984099999e+4`

Answer (score 1):

To save the number in a specific way, you can use optional parameter `fmt` of `np.savetxt()`. [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

In your case:

```
np.savetxt('Stress_strain_Anode.txt',np.c_[stressAnodeXX,stressAnodeYY], fmt='%.1f')
```

`f` is specifier wihch saves the number as decimal floating point.
`.1` Represents how many decimal numbers should be after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is not the numbers not being rounded, but not being appropiately formatted.
You could use the fmt keyword argument of numpy.savetxt to solve this. ([numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)):

```
np.savetxt('Stress_strain_Anode.txt', np.c_[stressAnodeXX,stressAnodeYY], fmt='%.1f')
```

Where `'%.1f'` is a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) which formats numbers with one decimal digit.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually `-32984.1`. Float representation in binary code [is not ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) so you see it in a bit confusing way. If you want, you can just round your result (but it is not needed):

`np.round(your_result_number, decimals=1)`

which will return:

`-32984.1`

---

More about your result:

`-3.2984099999e+4` has two confusing parts:

- `099999` in the end of number
- `e+4` in the end of output

`e+4` is a [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of your number. It means: "multiply it to `10^4=10000`. If you will do it, you will get `3.29841 * 10000 = 32984.1`

`099999`... in the end of the number appears because computer tries to represent decimal float number in binary code, which leads to small "errors". So your result is actually `-32984.1`.

Comment: If this is just a floating-point-precision-artifact, no rounding should ne necessary at all (or rather, the number will just be the same after rounding), right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My output is in array form not only 1 number. it is saved in .txt file.